# Parte da string em shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

Estou com dificuldade para conseguir separar parte de uma string em shell script.

```
T=$(df /dev/sda1)
echo $T

Saida:
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on /dev/sda1 81000912 11432088 65408212 15% /
```

Gostaria de pegar apenas o `15%`, de preferencia sem a porcentagem.
Estou testando o comando sed, porém não obtendo sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De facto `T=$(df /dev/sda1)` está a executar um comando `df ...` e
a guardar a sua saída em T.

(1) *afinar* o camando:
através de `man df` ou de `df -h` vê-se que há uma opção que
permite selecionar que campos queremos: `df --output=pcent`

```
$ df --output=pcent /
Use%
50%
```

(2) Selecionar apenas (ou seja `grep -o`) os números: `grep -Po '\d+'`

```
$ df --output=pcent / | grep -Po '\d+'
50
```

(3) Montar na script

```
T=$(df --output=pcent / |grep -Po '\d+')
echo $T
```

Comment: Algum comentário/sugestão acerca do voto negativo?

Answer (score 0):

Outra alternativa é a seguinte:

```
 T=$(df /dev/sda1 | awk '{print $5}' | tail -n 1 | cut -d '%' -f 1)
 echo $T
 50
```

O comando `df` é usado para relatar uso de espaço em disco do sistema de arquivos.

Já o `awk` é linguagem de programação que permite a manipulação de textos a partir de uma sequência de padrões.

O `tail` é um comando nativo do Linux que permite visualizar arquivos textos.

E por fim, o comando `cut`, seguindo a tradução livre, serve para "cortar" strings.

Então, a sequência de comandos detalhada fica da seguinte forma:

```
df /dev/sda1 # Relatar uso de espaço em disco do sistema de arquivos
awk '{print $5}' # Da saída anterior, pega só a coluna 5
tail -n 1 # Da saída anterior, retornar somente a última linha
cut -d '%' -f 1 # Da saída anterior, corta a partir de % para a esquerda
```

O símbolo `|` no shell, permite jogar para o comando seguinte o output do comando anterior.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Coloquei mais info senhor Bot !